# how can i select the team1 automatically show team2 name

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

have team1(tid number,tname varchar) here tid is primary key
and team2(tidn number,tnamet varchar) here tidn is primary key

here  select one team ex: India is team1 
now team2 automatically fill text box ex: Pakistan
 when we have to know the what opposite team for India ,or New Zealand,that time opposite team will be shown. in this task purely for match task

thanks

Comment: Don't hurry that much. Although it is *urgent*, you'd rather properly explain the problem. Why would Pakistan be chosen? Why not India (again)? Or Japan? Or New Zealand? How are those tables related? What business rule leads you from your wish to its solution?

Answer (score -2):

You must write a algorithm to choose a opponent team. The algorithm can be based on team position or you can choose randomly using SQL RAND() function like 
SELECT 
column 
FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
;
Ask me further if it's not clear for you. Thanks :)